Fantasy movie with evil man trying to live forever
Do you know the name of the movie that is in a similar style to Labyrinth with David Bowie, where there is an evil man who is trying to stay young forever. I don't think it is a very popular movie, it could be just a TV movie, maybe from the 1980s, and I think it is a fantasy film.  All I can remember is that there is some kind of mystical land where an evil man is trying to rule everyone, and I think is taking a potion to keep himself young.  
In the end, I believe the man is sort of reborn and everyone gives him a second chance, because he can't remember all the awful things he has done.

With a little creative license, this might match close to The Dark Crystal (1982). All descriptions are taken from the plot section of the Wikipedia page.
Similar in style to Labyrinth
Both movies were directed by Jim Henson, using a similar style.
A mystical land where an evil man is trying to rule everyone.
A thousand years ago on "another world", a magical crystal cracked, and two new races
appeared: the tyrannical, reptilian Skeksis, who use the power of the "Dark Crystal" to
continually replenish themselves, and hunchbacked natural wizards called Mystics.

I haven't seen the movie, but the Skeksis are described as tyrannical.
I think is taking a potion to keep himself young
[The Skeksis] use the power of the "Dark Crystal" to continually replenish themselves.

and
The Skeksis arrive to prepare for the immortality that they will gain from the
Conjunction if the Crystal is not restored.

The man is sort of reborn and everyone gives him a second chance
As Aughra, Jen and Fizzgig watch, the Mystics and Skeksis merge into tall glowing
beings...

